# Filter Xero Invoices by Tracking Category

Tags: mern, xero-api

I have been tasked with creating an API for Xero, the web application is MERN based and I have been using Xero's xero-node SDK. I need to be able to filter the invoices by tracking category but I can't seem to figure this out. I have read that the Tracking Categories would be under the lineItems key-value pair but all 10,000 invoices have an empty array as the value for lineItems . Below is an example of a typical invoice JSON object if that help.

```
  {
    "type": "ACCPAY",
    "contact": {
      "contactID": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
      "name": "name",
      "contactPersons": [],
      "addresses": [],
      "phones": [],
      "contactGroups": [],
      "hasValidationErrors": false
    },
    "lineItems": [],
    "date": "2021-09-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "dueDate": "2021-09-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "lineAmountTypes": "Inclusive",
    "invoiceNumber": "1234",
    "reference": "",
    "currencyCode": "GBP",
    "currencyRate": 1,
    "status": "PAID",
    "subTotal": 9.17,
    "totalTax": 1.83,
    "total": 11,
    "invoiceID": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
    "hasAttachments": true,
    "isDiscounted": false,
    "payments": [
      {
        "date": "2021-09-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "currencyRate": 1,
        "amount": 11,
        "reference": "",
        "paymentID": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
        "hasAccount": false,
        "hasValidationErrors": false
      }
    ],
    "prepayments": [],
    "overpayments": [],
    "amountDue": 0,
    "amountPaid": 11,
    "fullyPaidOnDate": "2021-09-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "amountCredited": 0,
    "updatedDateUTC": "2021-10-06T15:26:34.717Z",
    "creditNotes": [],
    "hasErrors": false
  }
```

What I tried

```
let allInvoices = await xero.accountingApi.getInvoices(tenantID);
allInvoices = allInvoices.body.invoices;

const invoicesWithTrackingCategory = allInvoices.filter(invoice => {
if (invoice.contact.name === targetTrackingCategoryName) {
        return invoice
    }
});

const filteredPayments = invoicesWithTrackingCategory.filter(invoice => {
    const paymentDate = invoice.dueDate;
    return paymentDate >= startDate && paymentDate <= endDate
});
```

I understand that invoice.contact.name is different to the tracking categories. The invoice.contact.name values are the names of the companies that the invoices are under. We have two kinds of tracking categories, one for Projects, and one for Build Categories. I need to filter by Projects.

Comment: I've only used Xero's API with cURL and Python, but Xero will only return line item details if you include the page parameter. This means it'll only return 100 records at a time and pagination will be required instead of all records being returned, but no line item details like you currently have it set up.

Comment: @AdamDS Yeah look like that is the issue. Thanks for the pointer, I will update with working code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I seem to have finally managed to create a function that can create a JSON object containing all invoices, with the lineItems included. Thank you to @AdamDS for pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT: I should probably mention that this will only work if you need to collate less than or equal to 500,000 invoices, as the daily limit is 5000 calls.

```
    // Define Base Variables
    const targetTrackingCategoryName = 'Tracking Category Name';
    let pageNumber = 0;
    let allInvoices = [];
    let fetchedInvoices = [];


    // Function for rate limited api calls
    async function rateLimitedApiCalls() {
        try {

            // Loop through all pages
            console.log('Loop through all pages')
            do {

                // Get all invoices (max: 100) for each page while number of invoices returned = 100
                const response = await xero.accountingApi.getInvoices(tenantID, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, pageNumber);
                fetchedInvoices  = response.body.invoices;

                if (fetchedInvoices.length > 0) {
                    allInvoices = allInvoices.concat(fetchedInvoices);
                    pageNumber++;
                }

                console.log('Page:', pageNumber, 'Invoices:', allInvoices.length)
            } while (fetchedInvoices.length === 100);


            // Filter payments by Tracking Category. Two tracking categories possible therefore tracking category could be in position 0 or 1 in the array
            console.log('Filter payments by Tracking Category')
            const filteredPayments = allInvoices.filter(invoice => {
                
                // Check all lineItems within the Array and return if at least one passes the test
                return invoice.lineItems.some(lineItem => {
                    const trackingCategory1 = lineItem.tracking?.[0]?.option;
                    const trackingCategory2 = lineItem.tracking?.[1]?.option;
                    return trackingCategory1 === targetTrackingCategoryName || trackingCategory2 === targetTrackingCategoryName;
                });
            });


            // Output filtered payments to JSON object (this is just for testing purposes, should output to MongoDB)
            console.log('Output filtered payments');
            fs.writeFile('Xero Data/FilteredPayments.json', JSON.stringify(filteredPayments, null, 2), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
            });


            console.log('Data Retrieved');
            res.status(200).send('Data Retrieved')
        } catch (error) {

            // If error, check if error is due to Xero limiting api calls, if so, retry call after specified time, else, log error in console
            if (error.response && error.response.headers['x-rate-limit-problem'] === 'minute') {
                const retryAfter = parseInt(error.response.headers['retry-after'], 10);
                console.log('Rate Limited, retry call in', retryAfter, 'seconds');
                setTimeout(() => {
                    rateLimitedApiCalls();
                }, retryAfter * 1000);
            } else {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
        }
    }

    // Make rate limited api calls
    console.log('Make rate limited api calls');
    rateLimitedApiCalls();
```